# Ideal MySQL settings

Tags: mysql, settings

I have an affiliate webshop with a large products database. 3.000.000+ records and it uses 4,3 GiB (InnoDB type).

I want to expand the database but i'm looking for the most optimal MySQL configuration.

Server information:

```
Operating system    Debian Linux 7.4
Real memory 5.57 GB used, 31.39 GB total 
Local disk space    198.34 GB used, 707.74 GB total 
Virtual memory  29.35 MB used, 1021.99 MB total 
Apache2 webserver
MySQL version 5.5.35
```

.

This is my MySQLTuner result:

```
MySQLTuner 1.3.0 
[OK] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.35-0+wheezy1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics --------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 40M (Tables: 288)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 2G (Tables: 22)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 58

-------- Security Recommendations  --------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics --------
[--] Up for: 3d 20h 4m 45s (17M q [52.042 qps], 418K conn, TX: 19B, RX: 3B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 52% / 48%
[--] Total buffers: 3.2G global + 24.4M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 6.8G (21% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (49/17M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 30% (46/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 3.0G/20.9M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (726M cached / 10K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 72.3% (8M cached / 12M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 3831
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (399 temp sorts / 690K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 4229
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 14% (2K on disk / 18K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (119 created / 418K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (413 open / 153K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 29% (646/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (9M immediate / 9M locks)
[!!] InnoDB  buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/2.9G
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0

-------- Recommendations --------
General recommendations:
Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C

Variables to adjust:
query_cache_size (> 64M)
join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
table_open_cache (> 1024)
innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 2G)
```

I can change most of the variables to adjust, but i don't know what the most optimal setting is. Is here a database expert among us who can advise me?

I already set indexes for queries and joins properly.